# Overriding equals method for comparing two fractions

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I'm currently working on a project where I need to compare two fractions. I have not done such a thing before, overriding a method, so I need a little help.

Here is the thing that bothers me;

So I have a class called fraction, and in that class, I have two fields.

```
public class Fraction {

private int denominator;
private int numerator;

public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {

    //Throwing an error if the denominator is 0.
    if (denominator == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Denominator cannot be zero!");
    }
    //When both numbers are negative
    if (denominator < 0 && numerator < 0) {
        denominator *= -1;
        numerator *= -1;
    }
    //When the numerator is negative
    if (denominator < 0 && numerator > 0) {
        denominator *= -1;
        numerator *= -1;
    }

    this.denominator = denominator;
    this.numerator = numerator;
}

public Fraction(int numerator) {
    this.numerator = numerator;
    this.denominator = 1;
}

public Fraction() {
    this.numerator = 0;
    this.denominator = 1;
}
```

I also have a couple of other useful methods for me to compare two fractions like this:

```
//converts the current fraction to the lowest terms
public void toLowestTerms() {
    int reminder = 0, gcd = 0;
    int up = numerator, bottom = denominator;

    while (up != 0 && bottom != 0) {
        reminder = up % bottom;
        up = bottom;
        bottom = reminder;
        gcd = up;
    }
    numerator /= gcd;
    denominator /= gcd;
}
```

So here is the part I am stuck.

```
@Override
//must take in an "Object" to properly override the Object class's equals method, but should ultimately check if two fractions are equal
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    // If the object is compared with itself then return true
    if(obj == this){
        return true;
    }

    /* check if o is an instance of Complex or not
      "null instanceof [type]" also returns false */
    if (!(obj instanceof Fraction)) {
        return false;
    }

    //This object is created for
    Fraction compareObject = new Fraction(this.getNumerator(), this.getDenominator());
    compareObject.toLowestTerms();

    // typecast o to Fraction so that we can compare data members
    Fraction x = (Fraction) obj;

    //converting to the lowest terms to compare
    ((Fraction) obj).toLowestTerms();

    // Compare the data members and return accordingly
    return (compareObject.getNumerator()== x.getNumerator() && compareObject.getDenominator() == x.getDenominator());
}
```

Is this the right thing to do, or is there a way to do this properly?
Technically I am creating an object to make use of the toLowestTerms method. 
Because when I want to compare, for example, 1/2 == 12/24, I need to reduce the numerator and denominator to do a good check.

```
'Fraction compareObject = new Fraction(this.getNumerator(), this.getDenominator());
compareObject.toLowestTerms();`
```

Comment: The idea of copying the fraction so you can call `toLowestTerms()` without changing the original object is good, but you should do this the same for the given `obj` or `x` object, otherwise you are changing the object which is coming in to the `equals()` method.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Oh, that's very true. So should I create a little while loop and find the lowest terms and compare it like that?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems good to me, I think it will work. I would add a few points, mostly about your comments:

1.

> If the object is compared with itself then return true

If the object is identical (i.e. the same instance)

2.

> instance of Complex

You mean `instance of Fraction`?

3.
It seems your method `toLowestTerms` changes the current instance `this`. For that reason, you created a new instance to represent `this`, called `compareObject`, I can only assume so that you don't alter `this` when compare is called (a good thing!). But for the parameter `obj`, you are altering the instance! You did not make a copy. You can simply solve this by making the copy as well, but might I suggest that your `toLowestTerms` method returns a new copy of `Fraction` with the lowest terms? Then you can safely call it on both `this` and `obj`, get fresh new copies, and compare both.

4.
A even more deep design decision would be to force call `toLowestTerms` on the constructor/setters. So that it's impossible to have a `Fraction` that is not on the lowest terms. That would greatly simplify methods like `equals`, `hashCode`. But that is a deeper design decision you would need to make. If you do so, you can take a look at a library called Lombok who would generate equals and hashCode for you based on the properties of the class! But will not do further calculations like `toLowestTerms`.

5.
If you are implementing equals, you probably want to implement hashCode as well, and make sure they are compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, so simply creating another object with 'obj' won't change the values permanently but allow me to compare appropriately.